# Intermediate Table with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm working in a Webapp and I have a problems to work with a intermediate table, these are my tables in mysql:

**User:**

- Integer:id
- String:name
- String:email
- String:phone

**Exercise:**

- Integer:id
- String:name
- String:description

**User_Exercise:**

- Integer:id
- Integer:id_user
- Integer:id_exercise
- Integer:record

So, what I want to do is that when I create an exercise, it be created one row for each user with the exercise-id that I have created it before. Later the user could change his record in this exercise.

I have thought to create a model to handle the user_exercise's table but I don't know if there is some way to do this better or not.

So, There are some way to do this without create a new model?

PD: Sorry for my terrible english

Comment: Yes, this is a many-many relationship. Look up how to do those in Laravel, your user_exercise table becomes a pivot table.

Comment: @ShitizGarg Really I have seen already how to do a many-many relationship in the Laravel doc, but I didn't seen about the pivot table, I'm going to read it again and look up how to do pivot table. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a seperate model for `User_Exercise`

You can use `$this->belongsToMany` from base Model i.e., `User`

`Note :`

For insert process you can get the parent id by

`$insertUser = User::create($userData);`

then

`$insertUser->id` for taking the last insert id

And then to retrieve with respect to `User_Exercise` you shall use `$this->belongsToMany` from your `User` Model

**Example**

Have this in your `User` Model

```
public function getUser() {
return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'excercise_name', 'user_id', 'excercise_id')->select(array('exercise.id', 'excercise.name'));
}
```

And Get the data you need from any Controller like this

`$userData = User::find($userId)->getUser;`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The problem is that the user can't edit his record in table user_exercise. For example: I have two user in my BD, when I create a new exercise, in the  user_exercise table are created two rows: [user_id 1, exercise _id, record = 0] and [user_id_2, exercise _id, record = 0] . I want to allow that the users can modify his record.

Comment: @JuanManuelBareaMartínez Welcome :) Yeah, i can slightly understand the situation. But in such modification record, you need to delete the records related to the user in the `User_Excercise` model and the do a fresh entry for that particular user

Comment: Ok, I'll try do it how you say. Thanks !